# Order divs by ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs that I would like to order from lowest to highest based on their ID. The IDs, however, are decimal numbers up to 5DP.

They look like this:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="1.6125">...</div>
  <div id="1.585">...</div>
  <div id="1.60125">...</div>
  <div id="1.59125">...</div>
  <div id="1.62625">...</div>
</div>
```

I've seen this question: [How to order divs by id in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778899/how-to-order-divs-by-id-in-javascript) But when I change the askers example to be decimal numbers it does not order the divs for me.

Any help would be appreciated, either jQuery or JS is fine with me.

Many thanks,

G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `.children` of the `#main` div, then `sort()` them by extracting the `id` of each and comparing the difference, then append them to `#main` so that they'll be in order in the DOM. The `-` in the `sort` function will automatically cast the string `id`s to numbers:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const divs = [...main.children];
divs.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
divs.forEach(div => main.appendChild(div));
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="1.6125">1.6125</div>
  <div id="1.585">1.585</div>
  <div id="1.60125">1.60125</div>
  <div id="1.59125">1.59125</div>
  <div id="1.62625">1.62625</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the down vote - Must be some angry user who didn't answer quick enough. It worked perfect so thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is how the other post is comparing the ids.

Try this:

```
var main = document.getElementById( 'main' );

[].map.call( main.children, Object ).sort( function ( a, b ) {
    return +a.id - +b.id;
}).forEach( function ( elem ) {
    main.appendChild( elem );
});
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/x7gesv68/4/

Comment: It wasn't me - I'm still reviewing all answers

Comment: Apologies for the downvote - I have upvoted but already accepted the previous answer as it was first and works also. But many thanks for your answer